# Как защитить сайт от регистрации спам-ботов?

Tags: wordpress, реестр, спам

Удалил с сайта всех лишних юзеров, поставил каптчу, а спам боты все равно генерируются! Но происходит это только на рабочем сайте. На локалке и на бесплатном хостинге этого нет. Т.е. вариант генерации случайных ботов изнутри, при помощи вируса, отпадает. В настройках стоит подтверждение регистрации по электронной почте. Проверял - сам, без подтверждения по электронке, войти не могу. Откуда тысячи ботов? У них у всех реальные электронки?
В чем причина?
Посоветуйте решение.
Спасибо.

Comment: запретить регистрацию? ) и про "вирусы" - если у вас рабочий комп заражен, но антивирус на домашнем показывает что вирусов нет - значит на рабочем тоже их нет? Есть [утилитка](http://wp-cli.org/commands/user/), которая помогает при деплое, но она может и быть источником проблемы (ну не только она, просто это наглядный пример) К тому же - если без подтверждения у вас нет доступа, то это не значит, что доступа нет и для других. Вы же не будете ломать свою систему, а они могут

Comment: Речь не о рабочем компе, а о рабочем сайте на хостинге. Мой компьютер тут не при чем.

Comment: вы говорите - локально и на бесплатном хостинге вирусов нет, значит и здесь нет. Поэтому я и привел пример, где ваша логика не работает. На рабочем сайте может дыра в безопасности, которой пользуются, потому и регистрируются все подряд. А другие сайты просто не интересны, либо до них руки еще не дошли (т.е. проблема есть и там, но ее еще не воспользовались)

Comment: Как решить проблему?.
Спасибо.
 Сайт на Wordpress

Comment: На всякий случай - стоит известный плагин Budypress - соц сеть.

Comment: Недавно было что-то про вирусы, но так и не нашел. Нашел только [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463180/5079), но там немного не то, хотя и это может пригодиться + надо [это](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) почитать

Comment: А как они регистрируются, если без подтверждения по емейл войти нельзя?

Comment: Исходя из Вашей ссылке, поискал в файлах сайта "window.a1336404323 = 1;!function(){var o=JSON.parse". Не нашел.

Comment: Посмотрите как называется та php через которую в штатном режиме работает регистрация. Потом посмотрите в access.log вашего сайта и выберите из него все строки с этой php. Если вдруг их немного - значит точно дыра, а если много - то дыра либо конкретно в этом файле, либо боты умные. Кстати, современные боты иногда такие капчи распознают, которые сам не прочитаешь

Comment: Да, если увидите в логе записи явно относящиеся к боту то по его ip все записи выберите из лога и сравните с тем, что оставляет обычный пользователь. Надо определить а загружает ли бот графику, js и от этой информации можно будет уже дальше двигаться

Comment: "А как они регистрируются, если без подтверждения по емейл войти нельзя?" Все боты умеют забирать подтверждение с email и создать кучу адресов не проблема на бесплатных сервисах. А вот выполнять js код крайне малое количество умеет ;)

Comment: А какая капча стоит? Можете дать сайт? Просто интересно что капча есть а боты все равно ломятся... Неужели сайт такой привлекательный)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте комбинацию плагинов Akisment и JetPack

Akisment Не дает нагрузку на сайт, jetpack наоборот ускорит, и также имеет антиспам.

Поискал парочку плагинов для решения проблемы.
Надеюсь должно помочь. Ваша проблема заключается именно с регистрацией, решение проблемы заключается в дополнительном поле. Боты запрограммированы под стандартные поля при регистрации.

**WP Spam Shield Anti-Spam**
Защищает от автоспамботов, генерирует проверочные поля(кстати это и есть решение вашей проблемы, так как боты понимают только стандартные поля авторизации)

**Grow Map Anti Spambot Plugin**
Имеет блокирующую спам контактную форму.

**Register Plus Redux** 
 добавляет дополнительные поля непосредственно в форму регистрации.

Опробуйте плагины и попробуйте с другого браузера зайти на свой сайт и зарегатся. Если появляются дополнительные поля то проблема ваша решена. Если нет то будем решать кодом.

Comment: Я так понял, что Akisment - защита от спама в комментариях, а JetPack - защита от входа на сайт методом подбора ключей к уже существующим аккаунтам. У меня же проблема с регистрацией на сайте новых спам-ботов.
Как мне могут помочь эти два плагина?
Спасибо.

Comment: Я вас понял. Есть два варианта поставить капчу( но это даже обычным пользователям надоедает) или же немного пошарится в коде.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Каптча стоит. Я же писал.

Comment: Так написал несколько плагинов( которые  дадут вам защиту от регистрации на сайте ботов.